# PyCharm autocomplete does not work with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I've just installed PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1 and tried to make a simple pygame project in it. I found that code completion runs in a weird way. In this case:

```
from pygame import event
event.
```

when I type `event.` a completion popup with `event` methods shows immediately. But in the second case:

```
import pygame
pygame.event.
```

a popup contains only `object` methods.

How can I learn the autocomplete tool to look deeper into the library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than creating your own [skeletons](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons), you can't. You can make pycharm a little better a code completion if you enable the following:

[image]

But other than that, you're out of luck. Python is hard to make code completion for because its a dynamic language, and stubs (skeletons) don't exist for everything.

Comment: Why can't the IDE make use of ipython, which has awesome autocompletion?

Comment: Because iPython is a console, and PyCharm's editor is an editor. In iPython, what you're actually doing is running a heavy debugger too, to inspect all the stuff that you're asking python to do.

Answer (score 4):

I tried Daid's answer (removing the try/except in **init**.py) and it didn't work, but it was very close! Here is how you can fix it specifically for pygame:

1. Go to your pygame folder and open **init**.py in a text editor
2. Navigate to the import section with the try/except clauses (around line 109)
3. Change the format from *import pygame.module* to *from pygame import module* for the modules you want

For example, change

```
try: import pygame.event
```

to

```
try: from pygame import event
```

Restart PyCharm and it should work :)

Comment: I've changed the import statements as you suggested and in addition triggered File → Invalidate Caches / Restart (took over 30 minutes!) and now autocomplete works for pygame (mostly). Unfortunately, PyCharm still collects errors like this during inspection: "Cannot find reference 'load' in 'image.py'. Thanks, anyways!

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how pygame is constructed.

The:

```
python\Lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py
```

File contains the following construction:

```
try: import pygame.cdrom
except (ImportError,IOError):cdrom=MissingModule("cdrom", geterror(), 1)
```

Which allows missing imports. However, this confuses pycharm. Removing the try+except will fix the pycharm auto completion.